# How can I access item details?

Tags: steam

Take a look at these:

- http://steamcommunity.com/economy/item/440/2/1844108053/
- http://steamcommunity.com/economy/itemhover/440/2/1844108053/?l=english&o_url=onehitkiller

The first one's just an icon.  The second is a specific person's item.  Is there a way I can view item details without needing an owner?

Comment: Can you be more clear? What "ID thing"? Where did you get that address? Does it refer to a specific item?

Comment: @PaulMarshall Seems pretty clear to me.  The first is a link to the item (a TF2 item).  The second is that item in a person's inventory.  The second link has a product description, but this requires a link to a user's inventory.  Question is, can you get the product description without needing a user?

Answer (score 1):

An option available to you, for tradable items, is to view them on the Steam market.   You can search for the item and then view the items description from the Marketplace.  Some items will also contain links to Wiki pages (if available), such as the Horrific Headsplitter you posted.